# Decomposition of complex Hilbert space using infinite family of orthogonal subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over the complex numbers. Let $(X_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a family of closed subspaces such that: (i) $X_n \neq \{0\}$ and (ii) $X_n \perp X_m$ if $n \neq m$.
Set $X_0 := \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n^\bot$ and let $P_n$ denote the orthogonal projection onto $X_n$.

> a) Prove that each $x \in H$ admits a unique decomposition: $x = x_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n$ where $x_i \in X_i$ for all $i\geq0$ and $x_n = P_nx$ for each $n\geq1$.

I am familiar with the fact that if $A$ is a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$ then there is a unique decomposition of each element $x \in H$ such that $x = a + \hat{a}$ where $a \in A$ and $\hat{a} \in A^\bot$.

I am also familiar with the fact that for two subspaces $L_1, L_2$ of $H$, that $(L_1+L_2)^\bot = L_1^\bot \cap L_2^\bot$.

It's not obvious to me, however, how this can all be put together and extended to the case where we're taking an infinite number of subspaces of a Hilbert space.

> b) Given a bounded sequence $(\lambda)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of non-zero elements in $\mathbb{C}$, show that one defines an element $A \in B(H)$ by setting: $Ax = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda_n P_nx$ for each $x \in H$. Compute $|| A ||, \text{Ker}(A), A^*.$ Show that $A$ is normal. When is $A$ invertible?

For this part, I'm really not even sure where to start. Intuitively, it makes sense that one could define a bounded linear operator $Ax = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n x_n$, but I'm not so sure about the rest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hint: note that (trivially) $\{\sum_{n\geqslant 1}x_n\in H: x_n\in P_n\}= \overline{\bigoplus_{n\geqslant 1}P_n}$, just use the definition of closedness in a metric space to see it

Answer (score 3):

First (a). Define the subspace $$K=\bigoplus_{n}X_n=\{\sum_{n=1}^\infty h_n: h_n\in X_n \text{ for all }n\geq1, \sum_{n=1}^\infty\|h_n\|^2<\infty\} $$
where the $\bigoplus$ notation refers to the Hilbert space direct sum.
Verify that $K$ is a closed subspace of $H$. Compute now $K^\bot$. If $x\in \bigcap_nX_n^\bot$ and $\sum_nh_n\in K$, then $\langle x,\sum_nh_n\rangle=\sum_n\langle x,h_n\rangle=0$, so $x\in K^\bot$. On the other hand, it is easy to see that $X_n\subset K$ for all $n\geq1$, so $K^\bot\subset X_n^\bot$ and this is true for all $n$, so $K^\bot\subset\bigcap_nX_n^\bot$. This proves that $K^\bot=\bigcap_nX_n^\bot:=X_0$.

By the theorem you are familiar with, if $x\in H$ then we have that $x$ is written **uniquely** as $x=x_0+y$, where $x_0\in X_0$ and $y\in K$ and $y=P(x)$, where $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto $K$.

Claim: $P(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_n(x)$. First note that, since the $P_n$ are orthogonal projections we have that the partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^NP_n$ are projections for all $N\geq1$ (these are self-adjoint idempotent operators; if this confuses you, take the space $K_N=\{\sum_{n=1}^Nh_n: h_n\in X_n\text{ for all }n=1,\dots,N\}$ and verify that the projection onto $K_N$ is equal to $\sum_{n=1}^NP_n$).

So, since projections are contractions, we have that $\|\sum_{n=1}^NP_n(x)\|^2\leq\|x\|^2$, i.e. (by Parseval's identity) $\sum_{n=1}^N\|P_n(x)\|^2\leq\|x\|^2$ and this shows that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\|P_n(x)\|^2$ converges. Thus we have that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_n(x)\in K$.

If we show that $x-\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_n(x)\in X_0$ we are done, by the uniqueness of the decomposition. So take any element of $K$, say $\sum_{n=1}^\infty h_n$, where $h_n\in X_n$ and $\sum_{n}\|h_n\|^2<\infty$. Then
$$\langle x-\sum_nP_n(x),\sum_mh_m\rangle=\langle x,\sum_mh_m\rangle-\langle \sum_nP_n(x),\sum_mh_m\rangle=\sum_m\langle x,h_m\rangle-\sum_{n,m}\langle P_n(x),h_m\rangle=$$
$$=\sum_m\langle P_m(x),h_m\rangle-\sum_{n,m}\langle P_n(x),h_m\rangle=\sum_m\langle P_m(x),h_m\rangle-\sum_n\langle P_n(x),h_n\rangle=0$$
and we are done.

I am only hinting (b):

Show that $A$ is well-defined by (a). Observe that $\|Ax\|^2=\sum_n|\lambda_n|^2\|P_n(x)\|^2\leq\sup_n|\lambda_n|^2\cdot\|x\|^2$. Find the proper unit vectors $x$ to obtain $\|Ax\|^2\geq|\lambda_n|$ and conclude that $\|A\|=\sup_n|\lambda_n|$. Verify that $A^*x=\sum_n\bar{\lambda_n}P_n(x)$. The kernel should be easily computed at that point.

Comment: I am using the Hilbert space notation of direct sum (see e.g. Barbara Maccluer's book on functional analysis). Is the downvote based on this issue of notation?

Comment: @Masacroso The direct sum is an operation that can be formed on objects of many categories, one of them being  the category $\textbf{Hil}$ of Hilbert spaces. This is a functional analysis question, one has to consider direct sums of Banach spaces, Hilbert spaces, operator algebras and the like. Check out more functional analysis books. You will see this notation more and more.

Comment: @Masacroso I'm guessing you don't have enough experience in functional analysis, but $\bigoplus_n X_n$ is standard notation to denote the orthogonal direct sum of orthogonal closed subspaces of Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Also downvoting a perfectly good answer answer because you don't like the notation involved...

Comment: @QuantumSpace Thank you for saying this (the obvious), I appreciate it.

Comment: to add something: sorry @JustDroppedIn, you were right, the direct sum construction in the category of hilbert space is what you had written. I had ever seen Hilbert spaces but using notation of the category of vector spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Everything makes sense, I just want to double check some things. Is it correct that I get $ker(A) = \{x \in H: x_n = 0 \forall n \geq 1\} \simeq X_0$? Also, I think I get that A is normal because $A^*Ax = AA^*x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\lambda_n|^2 x_n$ for every $x \in H$. It seems to me that this is always invertible - one condition for $A$ to be invertible is that $A^*A \geq c I$ and $AA^* \geq cI$ for some $c\neq0$, which this meets. Is this all correct?

Comment: @Masacroso It's okay, no problem. But, as Quantumspace said, please do not downvote only based on notational issues, it is unfair to the effort put in the answer. Even if my notation was wrong, I could simply edit.

Comment: @gogoTOP You are right about the kernel. You are right about $A$ being normal always. Observe that $A^*A$ does not always satisfy $\geq cI$! what if $\lambda_n\to0$? I think that the operator $A$ is invertible if and only if there exists $c>0$ so that $|\lambda_n|\geq c$ for all $n$. If you have any problems proving this claim, I can add some details.